# Should I create a new database or use an existing databases?

Tags: sql, database-design

I have multiple databases that sometimes interact with each other but are mostly independent. I now need build a new application that allows users to search though the data of the rest of the application (sort of searching through the history of the other applications).

So I'm going to need a dozen or so stored procedures/views that will access data from various databases.

Should I have each stored procedure/view on the database that is being queried? Or do I have a brand new database for this part of the application that gathers data from all other databases in views/SPs and just query that?

I think it should be the first option, but then where do I put the Login table that tracks user logins into this new report application? It doesn't belong in any other database. (each database has it's own login table, its just the way it was setup).

Comment: You just asked the basic question 'Data Warehousing' solves.  Create a centralized data model, ETL your data in, and report from there.

Comment: consider microservices

Comment: @Coding - there's a silly large number of these services now...tableau, qlik, tibco, sisense, domo, powerbi....the list goes on for quite sometime.  all on about the same level, bring in data from a variety of sources and link together in the cloud (or local...whichever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking here fits into the wide umbrella of business intelligence.

The problem you are going to hit quickly...reporting queries tend to be low number of queries and relatively resource intense (from a hardware point of view).  If you will, low volume high intensity.

The databases you are hitting are most likely high transaction databases.  IE they are dealing with a large number of smaller queries, either as a large number of single (or multiple) inserts or quick selects.  If you will, high volume low intensity queries.

Of course, these two models conflict heavily when trying to optimize them.  Running a reporting query that joins multiple tables and runs for several minutes will often lock tables or consume resources that prevent (or severely inhibit) the database from performing its day to day job.  If the system is configured for high number of small transactions, then your reporting query simply isn't going to get the resources it requires and the time lines on reporting results will be horribly long.

The answer here is the centralized data warehouse that collects the data from several sources and brings it together so it can be reported on.  It's usually 3 components, a centralized data model, an etl platform to load that data model from the several data sources, and a reporting platform that interacts with this data.  There are several third party potentials (listed in comments) that somewhat mimic the functionality of all three, or you can create these separately.

There are a few scenarios (usually due to an abundance of resources or a lack of traffic) where reporting direct from the production data of multiple data sources works, but those scenarios are pretty far and few between (usually never in an actual production environment).